# Error: "xyz is currently unavailable."

Tags: windows-xp, internet-explorer

When clicking internet options nothing comes up in windows xp/internet explorer on my virtual machine. I have also been able to communicate with the ip addresses of other NIC hardware in my network but currently no more. Is there a way to trouble shoot internet explorer and gain accessibility once more?

My problem is under Internet Explorer with Windows XP.

Comment: I've edited your post, but it's still vogue. Please provide more details.

Answer (score 0):

*/offtopic Assuming you mean OS=XP with used browser=IE*

Not completely sure I understand your question because of the
"When clicking internet options nothing comes up".

Maybe it sounds silly but, does XP show a (active/functional) network card at all?
(Do you have desktop item "My Network Places" visible on your desktop? could be handy)

Anyway, they way I read your question I would suggest some steps you could take to figure out what is going on/missing.

**1)** You could check with following command to see what happends?;

*(click Start | Run | Type: cmd | Click OK to go to command prompt | Type:*

```
ipconfig /all
```

*Press Enter to see result)*

Does it tell DHCP is active / does it show an IP-Address / does it show a DNS-server?
It should show several (internal) IP numbers, they could start with ie. :
10.0.0.* or 172.0.0.* or 192.0.0.*

What is shown after using ipconfig?

**2)** You could check if following is shown when you check the Properties of the Host Machine Network Card. Maybe it sounds silly but you can better be sure then still having unsolved issues;

```
Internet Protocol Version 4
```

If it is missing you have to add a service called "Internet Protocol Verision 4".
After that you have to tell (config) your Virtual Machine to use that network card.

**3)** Maybe also some to know, are you able to ping the Host Machine or ie. google at all?
*(click Start | Run | Type: cmd | Click OK to go to command prompt | Type:*

```
ping google.com
```

*Press Enter to see result)*

Because I am actualy more familiar with VMware and not using windows own Virtual Machine
 I have no idea if you can access the network config for the virtual machine directly/easy to be honest.